# How to sync windows 10 clock to internet from commandline?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, date-time, git-bash

I would like to be able to synchronize my windows 10 computer clock when it goes out of sync... From the commandline with 1 command.

This solution shows how to do it via settings.
https://superuser.com/a/1050717/44355

Is there a way to perform this via some windows 10 api on the commandline?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Start a PowerShell or CMD with elevated rights and use the [W32tm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb491016(v=technet.10)) command:

```
W32tm /resync /force
```

For further reading: [interesting article about the difference between NET TIME and W32tm](https://web.archive.org/web/20190110172756/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/w32time/2009/08/07/net-time-and-w32time/).

Answer (score 2):

`net time /set` also works and doesn't require admin rights.