# Unable to synchronize time on new Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows-10, sync

I just got a new Dell XPS 15 which runs Windows 10, and I seem unable to synchronize the time with the time servers. I've tried multiple solutions that I've found online, such as restarting Windows Time Service, switching to a different time server, disabling the firewall, etc. and nothing works. Windows cannot connect to the server and the connection times out.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

EDIT: I've tried the solutions posted in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1047359/cant-sync-windows-10-clock-to-the-internet), but they didn't work for me. They're essentially what I listed above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Sync Windows 10 Clock to The Internet](https://superuser.com/questions/1047359/cant-sync-windows-10-clock-to-the-internet)

Comment: I've tried the solutions suggested in that post but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Try to see if the free [neutron](http://keir.net/neutron.html) works for you, as an experiment.

Comment: Not sure what happened but the problem seemed to fix itself the next day. I didn't do anything or change anything. It just worked.
Nevertheless, thank you.